# Eclipse IDE project directory structure help [Java]

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, directory, structure

I have been learning Java and have had no problem with projects in which multiple .java files were in the same Default Package. 
I am now trying to separate code and create folders for images, but everything I have tried has failed.

How do I properly add folders for images and other classes, and properly set the path to it?
All paths should be relative to the project, I know that much ;_;

Here's a link to a picture of my IDE and error message from program output:

http://img262.imageshack.us/img262/8415/directory.png

Thanks!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, your Java code itself should go into a package, not the default package. Next, you may be able to refer to the image file by prepending src/ to your path:

"src/Textures/Crate.png"

But better would be to get the image as a resource, not as a file using the Class#getResourceAsStream.

Comment: Ok thanks, I get how the directory structure works. What should I call my package though? And what do I do with the default, right-click delete?

Comment: src is not a package, not at all. You create a package inside of src by right clicking on it and then clicking on New, then Package.  Then you can drag your source files into this package.

Answer (score 0):

Drag using the mouse your Textures folder to the LWJGL 6 project folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving `src/Textures/Crate.png`  as the path to the `FileInputStream` constructor.